# C# winforms Несколько форм

Tags: c#, winforms

Я создал приложение, и теперь я делаю для него авторизацию но не могу понять как сделать чтобы сначала открывалась форма авторизация, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаете форму-диалог авторизации, к примеру `LoginForm`, реализуете для нее логику `DialogResult`.

В главной форме в обработчике события `Form.Load` можно написать например так.

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var loginForm = new LoginForm();
    while (true)
    {
        switch (loginForm.ShowDialog(this))
        {
            case DialogResult.OK:
                return;
            case DialogResult.Cancel: 
                Application.Exit();
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Не удалось авторизоваться, попробуйте еще раз");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Все что вам осталось сделать - это реализовать возврат правильного `DialogResult`. Саму логику авторизации можете реализовать как в логинформе, так и в главной форме, или отдельном классе. Здесь уж как вам нравится.

Comment: Я к сожалению новичок и это мое первое приложение, не совсем понимаю куда надо вписать этот код

Comment: @Forum4anin в таком случае вам надо внимательно изучить, что за код я вам показал прежде чем его использовать. 1) как создать новую форму в проекте 2) что такое события и обработчики событий 3) как создать и использовать форму в качестве диалога 4) чем Show отличается от ShowDialog. А учить надо это потому что в первой строке ответа написано, куда - `в обработчике события Form.Load`. Чтобы его создать, надо в дизайнере ткнуть двойным кликом по форме. Но вы все равно далеко не продвинетесь, если не будете учить, что есть что.